# Pascal: Sum of digits within range

Tags: pascal, lazarus

How many positive integers less than 1000 have the sums of their digits equal to 6?

No idea on how to begin this using Pascal. On Python my script would look something like:

```
a = 1
b = 1000
for i in range(a,b):
........
```

I do not know how to access the digits. If someone could give me a heads up, I should be able to make some progress from here.

Comment: I'm trying to learn using Pascal for a competition. I need to learn to deal with situations like this, as there will be similar problems in the exam.

Comment: Wow.  I have not seen Pascal code in the last 15 or 20 years.  Your question is a blast from the past!  Of curiosity, may I ask, how have you come to program in Pascal today?

Comment: I see your answer to @MrPhi.  I had a college course in Pascal once, but the year was 1986.  Hopefully someone here remembers their Pascal.  I have forgotten it.

Comment: Would anybody be able to suggest a Python code at least, for a starter?

Comment: @Cloud Think of a way to get the last digit of any integral number. Then think of a way to transform a number by "removing" the last digit. Think about how this could be done arithmetically. For example, how to get `72` from `720` or `725`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, without the unnecessary conversion to string. It works by obtaining the right-most digit, adding its value to the accumulator `Total`, and then removing the rightmost digit by performing an integer division by 10, and repeating the process until we have nothing left.

```
var
  Value, Digit, Total, NumValues: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  NumValues := 0;

  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    Value := i;
    Total := 0;

    repeat
      Digit := Value mod 10;
      Total := Total + Digit;
      Value := Value div 10;
    until Value = 0;

    if Total = 6 then
      Inc(NumValues);
  end;

  WriteLn ('I found ', NumValues, ' numbers whose digits add up to six');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: That gives the correct answer of 28. If anyone is interested, I solved it by hand realizing the simple pattern here. There are 7 numbers that add up to 6 between 06-60. The are 6 numbers that add to 6 from 105-150, 5 numbers between 204-240 and so on. The pattern is 7+6+5+4+3+2+1=28. That's just to confirm that I wasn't using this as a sole means to complete my homework. I knew the answer, but wanted to simulate my algorithm and needed your help in order to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Your question basically is just "how is a for loop done in Pascal"... Just check the documentation, e.g. here: http://pascal-programming.info/lesson4.php#JUMP3

Also I smell homework. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link but what would the algorithm be?

Comment: I'll not solve your Australian Informatics Olympiad question for you ;) For every number you have to check if the sum of its digits is equal to 6 or not. If you don't manage to do it with that information you will have much bigger problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the snide comments about Pascal (it's still a viable language and lives at the heart of Delphi; its syntax has been borrowed for several 'modern' languages), this question is actually more complicated than one might think. First I'll show the program, then I'll explain.

```
var
 i, j, found, total: integer;
 s: string;

begin
 found:= 0;  // how many numbers whose digits add up to six
 for i:= 1 to 1000 do
  begin
   s:= inttostr (i);
   total:= 0;
   for j:= 1 to length (s) do
    total:= total + ord (s[j]) - ord ('0');
   if total = 6 then found:= found + 1;
  end;
 writeln ('I found ', found, ' numbers whose digits add up to six');
 readln
end.
```

The key is converting the index number (i) to a string (that's the 'inttostr (i)' line), then iterating over the digits of the string and summing them.

Comment: Too bad that the question didn't include "don't use strings".